# How to put a ListView in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment

I have a very big problem, well for me it is... So here it is.
I have a fragment that contains a TextView and a Button, when I click the button and choose contacts and I need there numbers and names stored in a ListView and to the right of the name and number I want a button that will be there so that the choosen contact can be deleted... I don't know if you understand, so in the ListView all that will be stored as a single item, NAME than under the name is the contact's NUMBER and on the right side is the delete button... I know that I have to use custom adapter, but I just don't get it.

Here is the code for my adapter

```
private class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

        public MessageAdapter(ArrayList<Message> messages) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, messages);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item_contact, null);
            }

            // Configure the view for this Contact
            Message m = getItem(position);

            TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contact_list_item_nameTextView);
            nameTextView.setText(m.getNames());

            TextView numberTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contact_list_item_numberTextView);
            numberTextView.setText(m.getNumbers());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

and here is what I try to do to put the contact in the list...

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT) {
            Uri result = data.getData();
            Log.v("Contact", "Got a result: " + result.toString());

            // get the contact id from the Uri
            String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

            // query for phone numbers for the selected contact id
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                    .query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                            new String[] { id },
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

            int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            int phoneType = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);
            int nameIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

            if (c.getCount() == 1) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                // contact has a single phone number, so there's no need to
                // display a second dialog
                mName = c.getString(nameIdx);
                mNumber = c.getString(phoneIdx);

                // Ovo radim ovako da bih mogao da ih upisem u fajl
                mMessage.setmNames(mName);
                mMessage.setmNumbers(mNumber);
                ((MessageAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                c.close();
            }
        }
```

So when I get the number and name of the selected contact I want to add it to the list, but I always get only the last selected number and name... Hope you understand what I mean, thank you.

And here are the `onCreate` and `onCreateView`, just in case:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Ovo ispod omogucava da se ugase sve activities i da se vrati na
            // pocetnu valjda
            // Zavisi sta smo stavili da nam bude parent class u xml manifest
            if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
                getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        mTextField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        mTextField.setText(mMessage.getmText());
        mTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                mMessage.setmText(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        mAddContactButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.message_contact);

        mAddContactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CONTACT);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

and onCreate

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMessage = new Message();

        UUID messageId = (UUID) getArguments()
                .getSerializable(EXTRA_MESSAGE_ID);

        mMessage = MessageLab.get(getActivity()).getMessage(messageId);

        mMessages = MessageLab.get(getActivity()).getMessages();

        MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(mMessages);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

the class

```
public class MessageFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<String> names_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> numbers_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Message> mMessages;

    private Message mMessage;

    private EditText mTextField;
    private Button mAddContactButton;

    private String mName, mNumber;
    private String build_name="", build_number="";

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE_ID = "com.falca.emergencymessage.message_id";

    private static final int REQUEST_CONTACT = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMessage = new Message();

        UUID messageId = (UUID) getArguments()
                .getSerializable(EXTRA_MESSAGE_ID);

        mMessage = MessageLab.get(getActivity()).getMessage(messageId);

        mMessages = MessageLab.get(getActivity()).getMessages();

        MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(mMessages);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Ovo ispod omogucava da se ugase sve activities i da se vrati na
            // pocetnu valjda
            // Zavisi sta smo stavili da nam bude parent class u xml manifest
            if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
                getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        mTextField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        mTextField.setText(mMessage.getmText());
        mTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                mMessage.setmText(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        mAddContactButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.message_contact);

        mAddContactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CONTACT);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT) {
            Uri result = data.getData();
            Log.v("Contact", "Got a result: " + result.toString());

            // get the contact id from the Uri
            String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

            // query for phone numbers for the selected contact id
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                    .query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                            new String[] { id },
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

            int phoneIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            int phoneType = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);
            int nameIdx = c.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

            if (c.getCount() > 1) { // contact has multiple phone numbers
                final CharSequence[] numbers = new CharSequence[c.getCount()];
                int i = 0;
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    mName = c.getString(nameIdx);
                    while (!c.isAfterLast()) { // for each phone number, add it
                                                // to the numbers array
                        String type = (String) Phone.getTypeLabel(
                                this.getResources(), c.getInt(phoneType), ""); // insert
                                                                                // a
                                                                                // type
                                                                                // string
                                                                                // in
                                                                                // front
                                                                                // of
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // number
                        String number = type + ": " + c.getString(phoneIdx);
                        numbers[i++] = number;
                        c.moveToNext();
                    }
                    // build and show a simple dialog that allows the user to
                    // select a number
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.select_contact_phone_number_and_type);
                    builder.setItems(numbers,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int item) {
                                    mNumber = (String) numbers[item];
                                    int index = mNumber.indexOf(":");
                                    mNumber = mNumber.substring(index + 2);

                                    // Ovo radim ovako da bih mogao da ih upisem
                                    // u fajl
                                    build_name += mName + ";";
                                    build_number += mNumber + ";";
                                    mMessage.setmNames(build_name);
                                    mMessage.setmNumbers(build_number);
                                    ((MessageAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.setOwnerActivity(getActivity());
                    alert.show();

                } else
                    Log.w("Contact", "No results");
            } else if (c.getCount() == 1) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                // contact has a single phone number, so there's no need to
                // display a second dialog
                mName = c.getString(nameIdx);
                mNumber = c.getString(phoneIdx);

                // Ovo radim ovako da bih mogao da ih upisem u fajl
                build_name += mName + ";";
                build_number += mNumber + ";";
                mMessage.setmNames(build_name);
                mMessage.setmNumbers(build_number);
                ((MessageAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Update the list view
        ((MessageAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    //MessageAdapter sluzi za rucno pravljenje liste poruka
    private class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

        public MessageAdapter(ArrayList<Message> messages) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, messages);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item_contact, null);
            }

            // Configure the view for this Message
            Message m = getItem(position);

            TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contact_list_item_nameTextView);
            nameTextView.setText(m.getmNames());

            TextView numberTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contact_list_item_numberTextView);
            numberTextView.setText(m.getmNumbers());

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public static MessageFragment newInstance(UUID messageId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_MESSAGE_ID, messageId);

        MessageFragment fragment = new MessageFragment();

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        MessageLab.get(getActivity()).saveMessages();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh and i extend ListFragment, not Fragment

Comment: So what are the issues you are experiencing? What goes wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code where `mMessages` is defined?

Comment: well the contact information (name and number) that is put in the list is always from the last selected contact... i have only one item in the list, when i add another the existing one is replaced with the new one, the new one is not added as second item in the list

Comment: i'll post the whole class code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you always update the same single mMessage field.

```
mMessage.setmNames(build_name);
mMessage.setmNumbers(build_number);
```

When you have a new entry you have to update you ArrayList mMessages. Add an entry to the list. The adapter always has this arrayList as data source so you have to update this arrayList.

So for every entry create a new message and add it to the mMessages array list.

Comment: Yeeesss, thank you, it worked... I fill so stupid now, thank you very much... I don't know how didn't see what I'm doing